# Images are placed side by side, how do I list them vertically?

Tags: php, html, css

i'm not sure how to make a break in this code, so the jaward images in this code below, shows multiple images in a vertical format (instead of showing them side by side horizontally).  Because the images are wide, it takes up to much space if I show them horizontally?  My coding knowledge is basic, so if you can tell me the specific location, it would be very helpful.. :).  I'm also not sure if I should use a page break

or a 
, span or other.

```
                    // Hack for jAwards integration, displays some medals of the user for Kunena 1.6
                $number_medals = 10;  // number of medals to show
                $query = "SELECT b.image, b.name"
            . "\n FROM #__jawards_awards AS a"
            . "\n LEFT JOIN #__jawards_medals AS b ON b.id = a.award"
            . "\n WHERE a.userid=". $this->profile->userid
            . "\n ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$number_medals;

        $database = &JFactory::getDbo(); 
        $database->setQuery( $query );
                $medals = $database->loadObjectList();

                // URL links to the jAwards-Tab for Community Builder which displays all
                // medals of the user - change to another URL of needed
                $awards_url=JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=userProfile&user='.$this->profile->userid."&tab=getawardstab");

                // CSS-class "ja_medals" allows individual styling of medal images and
                // container. "nobr" keeps the medals from breaking apart, display them 
                // in one row.
                $msg_jawards = "<div class=\"ja_medals\"><nobr>";
            foreach ($medals as $med){
        $msg_jawards.= "<a href=\"$awards_url\" title=\"$med->name\">" 
            . "<img style='border:0px;padding:0px;' src=\"".KUNENA_JLIVEURL."/images/medals/".$med->image ."\" alt=\"".$med->name."\" />"
            . "</a>";    
        }

        $msg_jawards.="</nobr></div>";
        unset($medals);
        echo $msg_jawards;

?>
```

Comment: You should read the comments in your code more carefully. They provide you the answer for your question.

Answer (score 2):

Add `<br/>` between images like this:

```
<img src="..." />
<br />
<img src="..." />
```

Comment: Hi, can you show me how and where to do this in the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<nobr>` tags from your code and add the following line in your stylesheet file

```
.ja_medals img { display: block; }
```

Comment: HI, adding this to my style sheet fixed it!  What is the <nobr> tag for?  Do I really need to remove this too?

Comment: Hi, removing the <nobr> tag took the site down, so I quickly put that tag back.  May I please ask if this tag needs to be removed (as the CSS change seemed to fix it even with the tag still there).How should I remove the tag exactly?  Should this be the best way: $msg_jawards = "<div class=\"ja_medals\"><>";

Comment: You can leave, it's simply not necessary. It tells the browser to not break the text line (images by default are treated the same way as text). Remove this bit as well '<>' , then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

$msg_jawards.= "name\">" 
            . "image ."\" alt=\"".$med->name."\" />"
            . "
"; 
    put < BR /> tag at the end.
or put your image inside a P tag